# How to pass my input from text area to my Interactive query

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a APEX application where I want to pass the text area input to my interactive grid report query

**Textarea**

ABC

XYZ

HSJKS

HSSK

JK

HSJK

**Query written on interactive report**

```
  select * from emp where food_id in (:P2_TEXTAREA);
```

**Note :** I have added a change event on `:P2_TEXTAREA` -> If any change happens the interactive report get refresh with data

The text entered in `TEXTAREA` is in vertical format and their is no space after every row. As I posted the question to show that I have entered newline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass multiple values using a single bind variable. What you need to do is use a sub-string match:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   emp
WHERE  CHR(10) || REPLACE(:P2_TEXTAREA, CHR(13)) || CHR(10)
         LIKE '%' || CHR(10) || food_id || CHR(10) || '%';
```

*Note: It is unclear if in your input the new line is CR/LF (windows) or just LF (unix/linux) so `REPLACE` is used to strip CR characters from the input to normalise it to just a LF character.*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=38ba45821aecac3ec66da440e355ee93)*

Answer (score 1):

It won't work that way; you'll have to split values into rows and then use the result in select statement.

I don't have your tables nor data so I'll use Scott's sample schema.

This table "simulates" page item:

```
SQL> create table test (p2_textarea varchar2(200));

Table created.
```

Sample values, each of them in a new row:

```
SQL> insert into test (p2_textarea) values(
  2  '10
  3  30');

1 row created.
```

Here's how:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from dept
  3  where deptno in (select regexp_substr(p2_textarea, '[^' ||chr(10)||']+', 1, level)
  4                   from test
  5                   connect by level <= regexp_count(p2_textarea, chr(10)) + 1
  6                  );

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        30 SALES          CHICAGO

SQL>
```

---

In your case, that would be

```
select * 
from emp 
where food_id in (select regexp_substr(:P2_TEXTAREA, '[^' ||chr(10)||']+', 1, level)
                  from test
                  connect by level <= regexp_count(:P2_TEXTAREA, chr(10)) + 1
                 );
```

Comment: without test table I want

Comment: It wouldn't harm if you actually read **everything** that has already been posted.

Comment: already the food_id as values on that basis filter should happen ... creation of test table should be avoided

Comment: Test table is here just to illustrate how it works. Code you need follows "In your case, that would be" statement. Did you not see it?